# Extract search engines' keywords with javascript and HTTP referer

Tags: javascript, http, parameters, referrer

I can't find anything googling. How can I extract search engine keywords for traffic sent to my website using javascript?

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'm looking for something that already exists, a tested library, however I can't find it.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907305/how-does-a-website-highlight-search-terms-you-used-in-the-search-engine

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was looking at a similar project, a jquery plugins that seems to know what it's doing - it even account for special characters. i think i will use it. http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an answer, rather than just a comment.  Your javascript code will need to inspect [document.referrer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp) (This may have been the magic keyword missing from your search).

Different search engines use different parameter names for the query, so you will need to know what to look for.  Google uses `q` Yahoo! appear to use `pqstr`.  Look for the value of that parameter in the referring url, and unencode it (with [unencodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)).

However, there is still [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907305/how-does-a-website-highlight-search-terms-you-used-in-the-search-engine) to check out.