# Get the keyword used in a google search

Tags: javascript, html

How do I get the text written in the Google search textbox using javascript?

**EDIT** : I am developing one Mozilla extension, i am using multiple functions to write the results of a Google search in a Google worksheet (Google docs), i have got everything i need except the keyword.

Comment: Using Javascript _in what_?

Comment: Are you using some kind of snippet from google? We need code to be able to help you.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907305/how-does-a-website-highlight-search-terms-you-used-in-the-search-engine ? Look at the Referer (sic) header.

Comment: Is this running in Google Docs? Please provide more details.

Comment: No it is a Mozilla extention, i am sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using regex

```
    /* get keyword */
var url = $('txtbox_location').getAttribute('value');;
var match = /&q=([^&]+)/.exec(url);
var keywordU = unescape(match[1]);
keywordU = keywordU.replace('+', ' ');
Application.console.log(keywordU);
```

where txtbox_location is a textbox in which i have the current URL