# Highlight Django Search result

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is my Model

```
class Acsd(models.Model):
    sequence = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, blank=True) 
    class Meta:     
        verbose_name = 'acsd'
        verbose_name_plural = 'acsd'
```

This is my view

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Acsd
    template_name = "search.html"
    context_object_name = 'search'
    paginate_by = 25


    def get_queryset(self): 
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Acsd.objects.filter(
           Q(description__icontains=query)
        )
        return object_list
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['result_string'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

and this is my template

```
<div class="row">
    {% for acsd in search %}
       <div class="col-md-2 " style="margin-top: 10px;">
         <b>{{acsd.description}}</b>
       </div>
</div>
```

I want to highlight the line containing the search string/phrase. And also want to show the previous and next line of that string/phrase containing line(if any). If I need to change my search mechanism, please suggest that too.

Something like google does. If we search "The Superhero", the results will make search string bold in the content.

- [image]

Comment: Can you give any example site?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907305/how-does-a-website-highlight-search-terms-you-used-in-the-search-engine

Comment: Thank you for the link, I want to know the django way of doing this!